# Ищу альтернативу Access

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть вопросы которые таблицы EXCEL не могут помочь ответить
Пришёл к выводу что нужен Access (по понятным для начинающих причинам)
Но в связи с политической обстановкой возникли опасения (тоже надеюсь понятно какие)
Вопрос: Нужна альтернатива Access - русифицированная, бесплатная, перспективная.

Comment: OO, LO и так далее. Замена, конечно, так себе... лучше заменять на связку интерфейс <-> БД.

Comment: Ну зачем вуалировать? Пишите правду

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что подобным вопросам не место здесь.